# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, openweathermap, weather-api

We are making a weather website using React-hooks.

Api got it from https://openweathermap.org/current#parameter.

But I can't read the temperature properties.

According to the website description,
main: main.temp Temperature. Unit Default: Kelvin, Metric: Celsius, Imperial: Fahrenheit.

Can't get properties inside JSON

What is the reason?

This is my Weather.jsx file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Weather = () => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const API_KEY = "1234567890"; // My Api key
  const COORDS = "coords";
  const baseUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";

  const getWeather = (lat, lon) => {
    fetch(
      `${baseUrl}weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric&lang={kr}`
    )
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (json) {
        const temperature = json.main.temp; // Error part!!!
        const place = json.name;
        setWeather(`${temperature} \n ${place}`);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
  }, []);
  const saveCoords = (coordsObj) => {
    localStorage.setItem(COORDS, JSON.stringify(coordsObj));
  };

  const weatherSuccess = (position) => {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    const coordsObj = {
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude,
    };
    saveCoords(coordsObj);
    getWeather(latitude, longitude);
  };

  const weatherError = () => {
    setError("위치 정보를 얻을 수 없습니다.");
  };

  const askForCoords = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(weatherSuccess, weatherError);
  };

  const loadCoords = () => {
    const loadedCoords = localStorage.getItem(COORDS);
    if (loadedCoords === null) {
      askForCoords();
    } else {
      const parsedCoords = JSON.parse(loadedCoords);
      getWeather(parsedCoords.latitude, parsedCoords.longitude);
    }
  };
  const init = () => {
    loadCoords();
  };
  init();

  return weather;
};
export default Weather;
```

This Weather.jsx file is shown in the Presenter.jsx file.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Weather from "../../Components/Weather";

const DetailPresenter = () => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <DetailContainer>
        <Weather/>  
      </DetailContainer> 
    </>
  );
};
export default DetailPresenter;
```

console.log result is

```
{coord: {…}, weather: Array(1), base: "stations", main: {…}, visibility: 10000, …}
base: "stations"
clouds: {all: 0}
cod: 200
coord: {lon: 126.79, lat: 37.65}
dt: 1608189833
id: 1842485
main: {temp: 0.08, feels_like: -4.98, temp_min: -1, temp_max: 1, pressure: 1030, …}
name: "Goyang-si"
sys: {type: 1, id: 8105, country: "KR", sunrise: 1608158521, sunset: 1608192958}
timezone: 32400
visibility: 10000
weather: [{…}]
wind: {speed: 2.1, deg: 300}
__proto__: Object
-----
{cod: "400", message: "wrong latitude"}
cod: "400"
message: "wrong latitude"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What is the JSON response shape? Can you include that in your question? All the error is saying is that `json.main` is undefined, so the data you are trying to get is possibly nested elsewhere.

Comment: @DrewReese I include that

Comment: That is what the API says it returns. What is the response you *actually* receive? Check the network tab in your browser's dev tools, set a breakpoint at the `const temperature = json.main.temp;` line or drop a `console.log(json)` just before it to see what the value is *when* your code is running.

Comment: I added the result.

Comment: *That* is the value of `json` *just before* `const temperature = json.main.temp;`? That doesn't appear to be right at all.

Comment: @DrewReese I added the result again, Why does the long latitude appear? My current position has been well received.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226080/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-eeez-kim).